# How to separate extracted column from excel into different lists or groups in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, openpyxl

I am reading a column from an excel file using openpyxl.

I have written code to get the column of data I need into excel but the data is separated by empty cells.

I want to group these data wherever the cell value is not None into 19 sets of countries so that I can use it later to calculate the mean and standard deviation for the 19 countries.

I don't want to hard code it using list slices. Instead I want to save these integers to a list or list of lists using a loop but im not sure how to because this is my first project with Python.

Here's my code:

```
    #Read PCT rankings project ratified results
#Beta

import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('PCT rankings project ratified results.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('PCT by IP firms')

row_counter=sheet.max_row
column_counter=sheet.max_column

print(row_counter)
print(column_counter)

#iterating over column of patent filings and trying to use empty cells to flag loop for it to append/store list of numbers before reaching the next non empty cell and repeat this everytime it happens(expecting 19 times) 

list=[]
for row in range(4,sheet.max_row +1):
    patent=sheet['I'+str(row)].value
    print(patent)
    if patent == None:
        list.append(patent)
print(list)
```

This is the output from Python giving you a visualisation of what I am trying to do.

Column I:
412
14
493
488
339
273
238
226
200
194
153
164
151
126
None
120
None
None
133
77
62
79
24
0
30
20
16
0
6
9
11
None
None
None
None
608
529
435
320
266
264
200
272
134
113
73
23
12
52
21

Comment: So, I see a lot of print statements but it appears that you're only printing the output from one of them - is this the output from the last one?  Is your goal to remove the Nones from that list?

Comment: Where is the country code/name?

Comment: Im only printing the output of the 'print(patent)' command and i shortened it because it was hundreds of cells. The print(list) at the bottom i did not include because it didn't give me the list i wanted

Comment: Hi Jeroen, the country names are in a different excel column. I have not figured out how to use them as a key for the groups of values because they are separated by even more None objects and random numbers

Comment: Ever heard of `pandas`? Kinda made for this task, and it can [read .xlsx files](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) directly.

Comment: FabienP - I read spent some time reading the manual for data frames; dicts and series in pandas but not enough to use it now. Dictionaries in particular require you to understand how the data is stored but when i have read more in depth i will try pandas. Do you know of a way to do what i want with openpyxl.

Comment: @FabienP Pandas doesn't read Excel files directly (it uses `xlrd` to do this) but I agree that for this kind of statistical analysis it makes more sense the writing your own code. openpyxl works well with Pandas.

Comment: My goal is to break the loop when there is an empty cell, record any values the loop has iterated through before the empty cell in a list. Then for the loop to continue from where it last stopped (cell.value = None) and then break again at the next instance of None and record this new area of cell.values in another list. This needs to happen over the whole list.

Comment: This is a fairly confusing question. Can you include the spreadsheet? Also, do you mean to say each list of countries should contain 19 countries? Or you want all countries to be equally divided into 19 lists? It sounds like there is an easy solution if you could clarify what you are trying to achieve.